# Disable Mail notifications on a per account basis

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-mail

In the iOS Mail app I have two accounts configured.
It is possibile to have notifications (banner and sounds) turned on only for one of the two accounts, or the setting in Notification under Settings is global for all the accounts?

I'm using an iPhone 4 with the latest version of iOS 5.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that, but you can set the Mail account you don't need to be notified to only fetch new mail when you open the app.

Go to `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Fetch New Data > Advanced` and change the schedule to **Manual**.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I'm getting the behaviour I wanted: non notifications from one of the accounts. Thanks!

Comment: Luckily this answer is out of date :-).

Answer (score 17):

This is possible with iOS 6. Under Settings → Notifications → Mail, notifications can be changed or disabled on a per-account basis.

Once you select the account: Choose notification settings - Notification Center and Alert Style (Off and None, I assume). Then choose "New Mail Sound". Select the New Mail Sound and Select the Vibration (None and None, I assume).

Answer (score -2):

you can accomplish this by holding the power button until the red dot shows up. swipe it over to the side and the notification will be disabled. thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps edit this to explain how you are preferentially toggling notifications by powering off iOS? Perhaps I'm mis understanding your answer due to brevity.