# How to disable notifications for a single calendar, in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, notifications

I have multiple calendars on my iPhone (iOS 6) and would like to know how to disable event notifications for just my work calendar (it's an Exchange account, if that makes any difference). I still need to be able to view, and add to, my work calendar though, so can't disable the whole thing.

**UPDATE**: The reason that I want to do this is because if I get a 'work' alert then I will either:

1. be in my office and using Outlook for such things, or
2. be on holiday/at home and not wanting to see work notifications.

The calendar needs to remain enabled because I constantly use it on my phone to plan free time (around work commitments) and also to enter out-of-office entries (e.g. dental appointments).

Comment: Do the answers for http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54857/disable-mail-notifications-on-a-per-account-basis help in your case as well?

Comment: Thanks Patrix but unfortunately neither answer would suffice for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain why? It might make it easier to come up with an answer for your case.

Comment: Sorry, but what you're after is not possible.

Comment: I really wish I could come up with a solution for this problem. Honestly, it would seem quite reasonable to be able to customize this - you can with calling, and messaging. But this part looks like something we will have to wait on Apple for. I have seriously looked and thought a lot about this one, but haven't been able to come up with even a hack (other then disabling all calendar event invitation alerts). Don't forget to let Apple know what you need (http://www.apple.com/feedback/). Maybe this will be one of the "200+ new features in iOS 7".

Comment: You can do this in iOS 8. Open the calendar app, go to calendars, click the (i) Icon of the calendar you want to silence and opt out notifications.

Comment: @ninjaPixel thanks for posting this question. Are you able to change the Accepted answer? bispymusic’s answer is good but no longer correct.

Comment: @mwfearnley this question was specifically about iOS6, the accepted answer is still valid for iOS6. I understand that ppl now finding this page probably aren't on iOS6, however the most recent answer is over 7 years old, so even if I wanted to change the accepted solution, there isn't one relevant for today's OS.

Comment: Fair enough - I guess I just found it unhelpful that I had to search past the accepted answer to find an up-to-date one.  But you're right, the accepted answer is the best for your specific question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer was written before iOS version 8 and doesn't reflect changes made in later versions.)

You cannot silence the alerts of a single calendar in iOS. Alerts utilize the Notification Center, and the Calendar options in the Notification Center apply to all calendars. I know this is not the answer you are hoping for.

The best option, as mentioned in the comments above, is to disable the calendar on your work account, when not desired, and re-enable it again when you need it. To do this, go to **Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Your Work Mail Account**. Slide off Calendars. This isn't a good option, admittedly, as you will have to re-download your calendars every time it's slid back on.

Another option is to keep calendars turned off for this account and use Exchange Outlook Web Access to access your calendars. This may be an even worse interface, however, as the OWA interface is not mobile-optimized.

My last suggestion is to use a third-party app to manage one of your calendars and the built-in Calendar app to manage the other. You can then disable Notifications on one of the two apps. You have to look potentially in two places for your calendar entries, but you will potentially get the granular control you need. Here are some calendar apps to examine: [Calvetica](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/calvetica-calendar/id385862462), [MiCal](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mical-missing-calendar/id392290576).

Comment: This is no longer true with iOS 8 (see my answer).

Answer (score 32):

[Yes, in iOS 8](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/tips/comments/turning-off-alerts-for-individual-calendars-in-ios-8):

> To do this, simply go into the Calendar app, tap the “Calendars” button in the bottom center to bring up your list of Calendars, and then tap the red “i” to the left of the calendar you’d like to change. Scrolling all the way to the bottom will reveal an “Event Alerts” option — simply toggle this OFF to prevent alarms in that calendar from showing up on the current device.

Comment: Unfortunately this only seems to be an option for iCloud and local calendars.  The little circled "i" doesn't appear next to my Google calendars, for example.  Good tip though!

Comment: @Matt Now in iOS 10 the "i" appears next to calendars from Google as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the following URL to define which calendars sync with your mobile device.

https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

That is still a load of messing around each time though.

Comment: Not a great answer, but a good workaround.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 3rd party calendar app just for their notification functions as a bodgy workaround.

I recommend Calvetiva, Agenda, or Tempus.

The workflow would go something like this:

- Choose a secondary calendar app.
- Configure you secondary calendar app
  to only use the calendars you want alerts for (steps vary on choice
  of app). Some (like Calvetica) are clever, and extend the alerts
  function by allowing a snooze option etc.
- Configure secondary
  calendar alerts and notifications via the normal settings>
  notifications app to show as you want them. They will only trigger
  for the active calendars in the app.
- Configure your normal calendar
  alerts to be off. Remove from Notification Centre, set alert style to
  none, and also go onto Sounds > alerts and set the calendar alert to
  none.

Now your existing calendar app will still have access to all calendars but won't alert, the secondary app will do alerting only for the active ones.

Downsides: You will need to periodically open and then shut the secondary calendar every so often in order for it to read the current alerts from the calendar data store and create it's own local notifications from them.

I hoped you could get round this by following the above steps but using the built in calendar as your selective alerting calendar (as it is always running and won't need to be opened to update), and using a replacement calendar app with all calendars shown but no alerts - sadly the normal Calendar app includes all calendars regardless of if you have turned a calendar off or not.